# How to install Kodak 3250 printer driver?

Tags: installation, drivers, printing, kodak

My system is Ubuntu 13.04 and I have a Kodak 3250 AIO printer. The test paper printed great and that's it.

I found `c2esp_25c-1_i386.deb` printer driver from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cupsdriverkodak/).
Trying to install w/USC I get the following error:

```
Dependency is not satisfiable: libcupsdriver1(>=1.4.0)
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After a little search, I found out that the `libcupsdriver1` package was not available on Raring (Ubuntu 13.04) :

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libcupsdriver1

I'm afraid waiting is the solution.
Raring Ringtail is not a LTS version of Ubuntu, and because it is still pretty recent, all packages from the last LTS (12.04, Precise Pangolin) haven't been transfered yet. Maybe Kodak provides a new Ubuntu/Linux driver...

EDIT : I found this project on Sourceforge, have a look : http://sourceforge.net/projects/cupsdriverkodak/

Comment: The package printer-driver-c2esp is in the Ubuntu repositories. Did you install it? Does it not provide all the functionality you require?

Comment: Downloaded printer-driver-c2esp. Unable to install with software center.It appears to be read only.

Comment: Thank you chili555 I'm having trouble installing the package printer-driver-c2espContacted. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Also contacted Kodak and they do not support Linux OS.

Comment: Chili555 I found the `c2esp_25c-1_i386.deb` printer driver in Ubuntu repositories. It's installed and printing. Thank you.